# verificar uma string com php

Tags: php

Galera tenho um input onde o usuário informa várias códigos de produtos, e o sistema retorna uma listinha.

Porém preciso de validar a `string` ou seja verificar es esta exatamente assim: 132,234,14,56

Ou seja, cada código separado por uma virgula.

Tentei fazer dessa forma, mas não funcionou:

```
if (preg_match('/^,/', $ids)) {
       echo "erro nas informações";
    }
```

OBS: Tem que ser sempre números inteiros, separados por , não pode terminar com a , não pode conter letras e nem espaço.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente, tente dá mais detalhes.

Comment: São só 4 códigos? São sempre 4 códigos? O número de dígitos varia? Pode terminar com `,`? Pode ter espaços? Pode ter letras? Essas, por exemplo, são algumas das coisas básicas que fazem toda a diferença ao responder.

Comment: não, o usuário pode informar quantos códigos ele quiser

Comment: As outras perguntas que eu fiz no comentário são importantes também. Se bem que aparentemente esses requisitos são pra resolver algum outro problema em outras partes do seu código, então a solução certa não seria essa que vc está pedindo, mas ao menos colocar todos os detalhes na pergunta pode ajudar você a obter a resposta que espera.

Comment: Desculpa, realmente não soube me expressar nessa pergunta. Bom vamos lá. Tem que ser sempre números inteiros, separados por `,` não pode terminar com a `,` não pode conter letras e nem espaço.

Comment: @HugoBorges procure [edit] a pergunta com essas informações e alguns exemplos mais variados do que pode e não pode. Nem todo mundo lê os comentários. Essa "burocracia" que a gente pede é pra te ajudar a chegar onde quer, e evitar que o pessoal perca tempo respondendo e a solução não resolva seu problema. Se conseguir deixar bem clara a pergunta, fica fácil a comunidade votar para reabertura da pergunta (e eventualmente melhoria na votação). A intenção é sempre ajudar, mas é preciso esse "Investimento" da sua parte pra que o problema fique o mais claro possível.

Comment: ok ja fiz isso ;) vlw

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi é uma lista contendo um número indeterminado de inteiros separados por vírgula. Então, ficaria assim:

```
if(preg_match("/^(\d+,)*\d+/",$ids)===false){
  echo "erro nas informações";
}
```

Comment: Eu tava postando isso aqui, mas acho a sua suficiente.`(\d+,)*\d+` (e ia colocar uma versão com espaços opcionais, e vírgula final opcional) - de qualquer forma, resta o @Hugo esclarecer melhor na pergunta o que ele quer.

Comment: Atualizei a expressão regular, agora tem espaços opcionais.

Comment: Se o autor da pergunta confirmar que é isso que ele quer, acho uma boa solução.

Comment: não pode conter espaços, apenas números inteiro separados por virgula

Comment: tentei a seguinte string `23,23,22` e não deu certo. Porém teria que dar certo

Comment: Porque não deu certo, ele tem que imprimir alguma mensagem quando a string é válida?

Comment: bom ele tem que imprimir o erro quando não for válido. Quando estiver correto ele não pode fazer nada.

Comment: Tinha um erro de digitação, agora deve dar certo!

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma é comparar a quantidade de vírgulas na string e a quantidade de dados que essas virgulas separam, exemplo:

```
$string = "132,234,14,56";

if(substr_count($string,",") == (count(array_filter(explode(",",$string))) - 1)){
  echo "Valida";
} else {
  echo "Invalida";
}
```

Em seu exemplo, você tem três virgulas que separam quatro valores, [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-count.php) conta a quantidade de vírgulas, e compara com a quantidade de valores fazendo um [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) na string e depois um [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) para eliminar vazios.

Você também pode validar os valores utilizando uma função callback no `array_filter`, exemplo:

```
$strings = array("132,234,14,56","132,234,14,56,ABC","132,234,14,56,",",132,234,14,56,ABC","1,2,3");

foreach ($strings as $string){

  if(substr_count($string,",") == (count(array_filter(explode(",",$string),'is_numeric')) - 1)){
    echo "String $string é válida";
  } else {
    echo "String $string é inválida";
  }
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**[Ideone](https://ideone.com/VvPrUp)**

Answer (score -2):

Experimenta com o [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
if (strpos($mystring, ".") !== false) {
    //código
}
```

Comment: mas ele funciona com ,?