# validando uma string

Tags: php

Galera preciso validar uma string com o php.

Esta string pode conter apenas números inteiro, e serão separados por vírgulas. Ela pode contar vários números, e não pode terminar e nem começar com vírgula.

**Exemplo de como deve ser:**

1 - 1,3,55,22,66,22,66 (o script não faz nada, pois esta correto)

2 - ,23,32,2323,3 (exibe mensagem que esta inválido)

3 - 23,32,2323,3, (exibe mensagem que esta inválido)

5 - 23,32,2323,3,g4,f (exibe mensagem que esta inválido)

**Tentei na seguinte forma:**

```
$contas = "1,3,55,22,66,22,66";
if(preg_match("/^(\d+\s*,\s*)*\d+)*/",$contas)===true){
     echo "erro informações invalidas";
}
```

Tentei assim mas não deu certo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Essa pergunta não é a mesma dessa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138656/verificar-uma-string-com-php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usei uma outra abordagem.
Veja se esta função resolve o seu problema:

```
function verificaContas($contas) {
  $arrContas = explode(",", $contas);
  $sucesso = true;
  foreach($arrContas as $conta) {
    if (!is_numeric($conta)){
        $sucesso = false;
        break;
    }
  }
  return $sucesso;
}
```

Código executado: http://ideone.com/2ClRw9